# Play Framework 2.6: NoClassDefFoundError: play/cache/DefaultCacheApi

Tags: java, playframework, ehcache, playframework-2.6, cacheapi

I am trying to upgrade my app from play 2.2.6 to play 2.6.3, and I'm stuck with this issue.

I've read answers to [@KdgDev's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107490/play-framework-2-4-noclassdeffounderror-play-api-cache-cacheplugin) and [@NikolajPL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229644/noclassdeffounderror-play-api-cache-cacheplugin) questions, which sound similar, but so far nothing helped.

I'm not sure where this problem originates, but I think it might be related to Redis DB connection, since it uses different caching method, and starting from play 2.5 default ehcahce should be disabled.

My conf file:

```
# Mongo configuration
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mongodb.name=mongoAbc
mongodb.host=localhost
mongodb.port=27017

application.global=api.abc


# Spring configuration
# ~~~~~
# Define what spring context should be used.
spring.context="components.xml"


# Router
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point.
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
# So for an application router like `conf/my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `my.application.controllers`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and `conf/controllers`)
# application.router=my.application.Routes


# Test configuration
# ~~~~~
# To create test/1.sql uncomment following lines:
#ebean.test="model.*"
#db.test.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
#db.test.url="postgres://abc:def@localhost:5432/abc"
#applyEvolutions.test=true


# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://abc:def@localhost:5432/abc"


# DB Pooling
# --------------
# In order to reduce lock contention and thus improve performance,
# each incoming connection request picks off a connection from a
# pool that has thread-affinity.
# The higher this number, the better your performance will be for the
# case when you have plenty of short-lived threads.
# Beyond a certain threshold, maintenance of these pools will start
# to have a negative effect on performance (and only for the case
# when connections on a partition start running out).
db.default.partitionCount=7

# The number of connections to create per partition. Setting this to
# 5 with 3 partitions means you will have 15 unique connections to the
# database. Note that BoneCP will not create all these connections in
# one go but rather start off with minConnectionsPerPartition and
# gradually increase connections as required.
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=30

# The number of initial connections, per partition.
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5

# When the available connections are about to run out, BoneCP will
# dynamically create new ones in batches. This property controls
# how many new connections to create in one go (up to a maximum of
# maxConnectionsPerPartition). Note: This is a per-partition setting.
db.default.acquireIncrement=1

# After attempting to acquire a connection and failing, try to
# connect this number of times before giving up.
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=10

# How long to wait before attempting to obtain a
# connection again after a failure.
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds

# The maximum time to wait before a call
# to getConnection is timed out.
db.default.connectionTimeout=1 second

# Idle max age
db.default.idleMaxAge=10 seconds

# This sets the time for a connection to remain idle before sending a test query to the DB.
# This is useful to prevent a DB from timing out connections on its end.
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=5 minutes

# An initial SQL statement that is run only when
# a connection is first created.
db.default.initSQL="SELECT 1"

# If enabled, log SQL statements being executed.
db.default.logStatements=false

# The maximum connection age.
db.default.maxConnectionAge=20 seconds

# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
# db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
ebean.default="model.*"
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true

# MailGun configuration
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mailgun.api.key=${?MAILGUN_API_KEY}
mailgun.domain=${?MAILGUN_DOMAIN}

# Uncomment to prevent sending real emails
# mail.disabled=true

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/),
# by providing an application-log.xml file in the conf directory.

#logger=OFF
#log.application=OFF
#log.play=OFF

# Redis
# ~~~~~
ehcacheplugin=disabled
redis.uri=${?REDISCLOUD_URL}

# The default cache module (EhCache) will be used for all non-named cache UNLESS this module (RedisModule)
# is the only cache module that was loaded. If this module is the only cache module being loaded,
# it will work as expected on named and non-named cache. To disable the default cache module so that this Redis Module
# can be the default cache you must put this in your configuration
# See https://github.com/playframework/play-plugins/tree/master/redis for reference
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"

# Redis module supports play 2.5 NamedCaches through key namespacing on a single Sedis pool.
# To add additional namepsaces besides the default (play), the configuration would
# look like play.cache.redis.bindCaches = ["db-cache", "user-cache", "session-cache"]
# See https://github.com/playframework/play-plugins/tree/master/redis for reference
play.cache.redis.bindCaches = ["db-cache", "user-cache", "session-cache"]

# Amazon
# ~~~~~
youtube.api.key=${?ABC_YOUTUBE_API_KEY}

# Akka
# Threadpool
# ~~~~~~~~~~
play {
    akka {
        akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
        loglevel = DEBUG
        jvm-exit-on-fatal-error = off
        log-config-on-start = off
        actor {
            default-dispatcher = {
                fork-join-executor {
                    parallelism-min = 50
                    parallelism-max = 120
                }
            }
            download-context = {
                fork-join-executor {
                    parallelism-min = 50
                    parallelism-max = 50
                }
            }
            conversion-context {
                fork-join-executor {
                    parallelism-min = 1
                    parallelism-factor = 1.0
                    parallelism-max = 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
akka.log-dead-letters = off
akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off

# Modules
# ~~~~~~~
play.modules.enabled  += "module.MongoDBModule"
play.modules.enabled  += "module.S3Module"

play.cache.defaultCache=default

play.cache.dispatcher = "contexts.blockingCacheDispatcher"

contexts {
    blockingCacheDispatcher {
        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-factor = 3.0
        }
    }
}
```

build.sbt

```
name := "abc-api"

version := "0.27.7"

lazy val abc_api = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

lazy val akkaVersion = "2.5.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  guice,
  ehcache,
  cacheApi,
  evolutions,
  "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm-api" % "3.1.1",
  "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0.RELEASE",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured
  "io.rest-assured" % "rest-assured" % "3.0.3" % "test",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.3.10.RELEASE",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test
  "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "4.3.10.RELEASE" % "test",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.188",
  "org.imgscalr" % "imgscalr-lib" % "4.2",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core
  "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.16",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers
  "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.16",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.6",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-collections4" % "4.1",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator
  "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.6",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3",
  // Deprecated - ? "commons-httpclient" % "commons-httpclient" % "3.1" exclude("org.apache.commons", "httpclient"),
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.9.0" % "test",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "2.0.2-beta" % "test",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.4",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jcodec/jcodec
  "org.jcodec" % "jcodec" % "0.2.1",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java
  "com.mashape.unirest" % "unirest-java" % "1.4.9",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.spullara.mustache.java/compiler
  "com.github.spullara.mustache.java" % "compiler" % "0.9.5",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl
  "xerces" % "xercesImpl" % "2.11.0",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.6.0-beta1",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock
  "com.github.tomakehurst" % "wiremock" % "2.8.0" % "test" pomOnly(),
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail
  "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.6.0",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core
  "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-core" % "3.2.4",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-healthchecks
  "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-healthchecks" % "3.2.4",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-jvm
  "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-jvm" % "3.2.4",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
  "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.10.3",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.helger/ph-css
  "com.helger" % "ph-css" % "5.0.4",
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.vandermeer/asciitable
  "de.vandermeer" % "asciitable" % "0.3.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-iteratees" % "2.6.1",
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play.modules/play-modules-redis_2.11
  "com.typesafe.play.modules" % "play-modules-redis_2.11" % "2.5.0",
  "org.easytesting" % "fest-assert" % "1.4" % "test",
    filters
)

javaOptions in Test ++= Seq(
    "-Dtest.timeout=10000000",
    "-Dconfig.file=conf/application-test.conf",
    "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M",
    "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC",
    "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
)

javacOptions in (Compile, compile) ++= Seq(
    "-Xlint",
    "-source",
    "1.8",
    "-target",
    "1.8"
)

scalacOptions += "-Yresolve-term-conflict:package"
```

plugins.sbt

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.3")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

// In order for DataService to work with spring we need to include the dependency here (see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/UIsRqnQ8x3g)
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.3.10.RELEASE"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist
libraryDependencies += "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.21.0-GA"
```

I am running my project with sbt and getting the following stacktrace:

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[error] application - 

! @758h3g5n5 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoClassDefFoundError: play/cache/DefaultCacheApi]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:190)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.play$core$server$AkkaHttpServer$$modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.play$core$server$AkkaHttpServer$$handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$5.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$5.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$23.onPush(Ops.scala:1172)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:499)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:462)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:368)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/cache/DefaultCacheApi
    at com.typesafe.play.redis.RedisModule.bindings(RedisModule.scala:61)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$class.guice(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:339)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModule$.guice(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:273)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$3$$anonfun$guiced$2.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:318)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$3$$anonfun$guiced$2.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:286)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.cache.DefaultCacheApi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.typesafe.play.redis.RedisModule.bindings(RedisModule.scala:61)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$class.guice(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:339)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModule$.guice(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:273)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$3$$anonfun$guiced$2.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:318)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$3$$anonfun$guiced$2.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the Typesafe Redis module, which is for either 2.3, 2.4 or 2.5. It's not compatible with 2.6, due to the fact that the cache implementation in Play 2.6 isn't binary compatible with the implementation in 2.5.

You have 3 options :

1) Use the default EHCache
2) Update the Redis module to be compatible with 2.6
3) Cook up your own implementation.